# Get 2 weeks of days from today using moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I'm in need of showing 14 days from today date in my react native app. For example assume today is 26th Friday. In my app i want to display a list of days as

```
26 - today
27 - saturday
28 - sunday
01 - monday
02 - tuesday
............
12 - friday
```

How would I get the days like this using momentjs or is there a better way to do this instead of using momentjs.
I referred the momentjs doucmentation and looked around for similar questions but could not find anything something similar to what i need to get.

Comment: MomentJS give you the current date ; you can just loop N times while adding a day each turn, and format as you want the output

Comment: You are right, there is a better way to do this. MomentJS will add 232kB overhead to every visit on your page. You can get what you need with a bit of plain javasript (fun) for about 500bytes. That's a 500x saving! Check out my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think MomentJS is total overkill for this and most simple date stuff! It's a pretty big/expensive library if you don't need it.

Edit:
Added the month name as asked in comment, I added a few comments too so you can follow the logic. Note this is only designed to 'cross over the end of one month' as 14 days will never cross over more, but a couple more lines of code could be added to handle lists longer than 28 days.

```js
function myFunction() {

  daysArr = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
  monthsArr = ['january' , 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
  // array of month names 

  var d = new Date()
  // var d = new Date(2021, 1, 25) 
  // you can test other dates by passing (year, month, day) into the date constructor 
  // note the months start at 0, february is 1, and so on

  var day = d.getDay() - 1
  var date = d.getDate()
  var month = d.getMonth() // get the month numerically - january is returned as 0 and so on
  var daysInMonth = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
  let daysList = ''

  for (let i=0; i<14; i++) {
    if (i===0) {
      daysList += date + ' - today - ' + monthsArr[month] + '<br>'
    } else {
      daysList += date + ' - ' + daysArr[day] + ' - ' + monthsArr[month] + '<br>'
      // add the month name from monthsArr to our print out
    }
    day++
    date++
    if (day === 7) {
        day=0
    }
    if (date > daysInMonth) {
      date=1
      month++ // increment the month so the rest of the list gets the next month name
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = daysList;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">List Days</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This answer suits my need really well. But what if i want to show the month as well. How do i show the correct month. For example if today is 26th,  for days 26,27,28 the  month will be feburary and for days 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 the month will be march. How do i show the month as well?

Comment: Hey @CraZyDroiD I added the month name, and a few comments to help you follow the logic, it's quite straight forward and a handy trick for playing with dates

Answer (score 2):

If you're using momentjs you could do something like: `moment().add(2, 'weeks')` to get the number of date 2 weeks from now.

To get the name of day 2 weeks from now you could do: `moment().add(2, 'weeks').format('dddd')`

```js
console.log(`${moment().add(2, 'weeks').format('DD')} - ${moment().add(2, 'weeks').format('dddd')}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

To get all date between today until a certain date you can do loop-while for it:

```js
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var now = startDate,
    dates = [];

  while (now.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
    dates.push(`${now.format('DD')} - ${now.format('dddd')}`);
    now.add(1, 'days');
  }
  return dates;
};

var fromDate = moment();
var toDate = moment().add(2, 'weeks');
var results = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(fromDate, toDate);
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use any library you could use the inbuilt Javascript method [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```js
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
  var now = startDate,
    dates = [];
  const options = { weekday: 'long'};

  while (now <= endDate) {
    dates.push(`${now.getDate()} - ${now.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)}`);
    now.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
  }
  return dates;
};

var from = new Date();
var to = new Date();
to.setDate(to.getDate()+14);

var results = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(from, to);
console.log(results);
```

You might also want to check [Parse Date Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/parseformat/) from momentjs docs.

Comment: I want to get all 14 days from today. How would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will do the same output as you need

```
let days = [];
days.push(moment().format("Do - dddd"));
for (let index = 1; index <= 14; index++) {
  let day = moment().subtract(index, "days").format("Do - dddd");
  days.push(day);
}
```

and then you print the array. of day in a way you like